# Multishipping data to view in magento

Tags: magento

I started work on magento site and now work on multishipping addresses.
Here Url is
    **checkout/multishipping/addresses/**

controllers is 
    **app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\MultishippingController.php**

and view is
    **frontend\base\default\template\checkout/multishipping/addresses.phtml**

But I can not find from where the data (product list with qty and addresses) is coming i.e. from which block or controller.
Could you please help me to find out.

Comment: you can see a block name by using template path hints from backend

Comment: Look like block is from Mage\Checkout\Block\Multishipping\Addresses.php but the data is displaying even the file deleted. And not echo anything from there.

Comment: which file you have deleted?  and have you choose store hint for particular store view from admin

Comment: deleted whole block folder.